# Does rails impose any automatic rules for password fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, passwords

Background:
User record creation in the application I'm working on is failing with errors "Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters)" and "Password confirmation is too short (minimum is 4 characters)".

Neither the User model nor any of its included models mentions passwords. The only places in the application where I can find them mentioned is in forms within the views and in the original database migrations. There is a `crypted_password` column, and a `password_salt` column in our users table. We are NOT using devise. The only `security_related` gems in our gemfile are `attr_encrypted` and `encryptor`, neither of which seem to mention any special treatment of passwords in their documentation.

So, since length validations and encryption are in fact happening, and I can't seem to track it down to a model or a gem, where might these rules be coming from? Is there a way I can disable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out our application also makes use of the AuthLogic gem, which adds its own validations on login and password by default. As per [this page of the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/authlogic/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/Password/Config:validate_password_field), the validations can be overridden in an application-wide configuration or in per-model configuration blocks.